# Android Studio 3 stable checking for update gives error - Studio does not have write access to

Tags: android-studio

On Mac "Sierra OS", Android Studio, when trying to update to Android Studio 3.0 it gives this error:

```
Studio does not have write access to /private/var/folders/xn/dgzclk4903q6gp3hm7sxndfm0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/B13F4083-E54C-4DEA-A067-42ACEC8C32C6/d/Android Studio.app/Contents. Please run it by a privileged user to update.
```

Is there a way to give it the permission? I don't want to copy it, like what other suggested by terminal line.

Comment: probably run it as root user?

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך אוהב אותך I try with sudo but not working, given this error: LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/Android Studio.app.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Android Studio with the new updates in difereent path and works okay.